# Ck-editor Undo action not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

I have faced Ck-editor undo action, while without editing any content in ckeditor, just insert cursor in ckeditor content box and undo action using undo menu or ctrl+z.

[image]

Then content is disappear(empty editor box visible) Like this:

[image]

Here my question is how to control undo action while didn't do any changes in ckeditor.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where your problem is.

Comment: "https://jsfiddle.net/magbed3t/"
Check the link, new ckeditor is integrated. But, in my case i get content from DB in first time and without edit any content and click on undo button, the editor visible as empty box.

Comment: How do you set the initial content? Still don't see any of your code in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: "https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjgef8x/"
loaded with initial content. Undo and redo are not enabled but in my case (see screenshot in above pic) undo is enable.

Comment: So in the fiddle it is working as intended? The editor object is created and the initial data is set. The undo button is disabled because nothing has changed to the content. So, what are you doing differently? Do you modify the editor object after this? Do you have any other javascript code running that can change the content of the editor?